# iOS Segment Button Alternative?

Tags: ios, xcode

Novice iOS developer here asking the community with some help on what I believe to be a segment button. I have seen this on other apps and I am trying to implement it myself but can't seem to find what to look for.

I have taken the image of a similar post on StackOverflow for the android version but I am looking for the iOS version. I am currently developing using objective-c.

[image]

When you switch from activities I want the underline to slide over to the active activity. Does anyone know how to do this or can navigate me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Use [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ //update the frame of your underline }];

Comment: If you don't want to implement your self check this control https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Comment: I think above comment should serve the purpose ? reply please.

Answer (score 1):

Add a red view under the buttons, and give it constraints of center x to both buttons but with different priorities (both of which need to be less than 1000). Whichever constraint has the higher priority will determine where the line ends up. You can raise the priority of the lower priority one, and then call layoutIfNeeded on the superview inside an animation block to slide the line over.